# Postgresql calculating minimal difference in time between records

Tags: postgresql, function, loops

I am trying to create a function that generates time differences. I first want to select a unique user, then all the records for this user and then calculate the difference of time between the points and the following point. It is ordered ascended and then should end up in a table like

```
id, user, time_read, timediff
0, test, 2019-10-12 21:15:02.000000, 0 
1, test, 2019-10-12 21:15:06.000000, 4 seconds
2, test, 2019-10-12 21:15:19.000000, 13 seconds
3, test, 2019-10-12 21:15:23.000000, 4 seconds
etcetera


CREATE TABLE newtable AS
    SELECT null::integer as id, null::character varying as aid,
           null::timestamp, null::interval as timediff;

do $$
declare
   i character varying;
   r mytable;
   e timestamp;
   counter integer := 0;
begin
    for i in
        select distinct(aid) from mytable
    loop
        for r in
            select time_read from mytable
            where aid = i order by time_read asc
        loop
            for e in r
                insert into newtable
                counter, 
                    select aid, e,
                        e-sv.time_read::timestamp
                    from mytable as sv
                    where aid = i and e <> sv.time_read 
                    order by e-sv.time_read::timestamp
                    limit 1;
                counter += 1;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    raise notice '%', i||tripcount::character varying;
end; $$
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: You don't need a loop for this to begin with. This can be done with a single `insert into  ... select ...` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you even need a custom function? You could use a `WINDOW` function:

```
CREATE TABLE time_diff(id integer, "user" varchar, time_read timestamp);
INSERT INTO time_diff VALUES (0, 'test', '2019-10-12 21:15:02.000000');
INSERT INTO time_diff VALUES (1, 'test', '2019-10-12 21:15:06.000000');
INSERT INTO time_diff VALUES (2, 'test', '2019-10-12 21:15:19.000000');
INSERT INTO time_diff VALUES (3, 'test', '2019-10-12 21:15:23.000000');


SELECT 
    id, "user", time_read, 
    COALESCE(time_read - LAG(time_read, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY user), '0') AS diff 
FROM 
    time_diff 
ORDER BY 
    time_read;

 id | user |      time_read      |   diff   
----+------+---------------------+----------
  0 | test | 10/12/2019 21:15:02 | 00:00:00
  1 | test | 10/12/2019 21:15:06 | 00:00:04
  2 | test | 10/12/2019 21:15:19 | 00:00:13
  3 | test | 10/12/2019 21:15:23 | 00:00:04
```